# OpenCV translation vector having near 0 value for z coordinate

Tags: c++, opencv, slam, visual-odometry

Hope that everyone is doing well.

I'm working in visual SLAM. The video I'm using right now is a car driving down a road. The issue is that the rotation matrix seems right, however, the translation vector I get from `decomposeEssentialMat` seems to have very high `x` and `y` values and a near `0` `z` value even though the camera should mostly only be moving along the z axis as the car is driving forwards.

Attached is the code and some sample output:

```
TRANSLATION: [-0.9247823026950661;
 -0.3804958988176681;
 -0.0007507362692929707]
TRANSLATION: [0.8785245421613305;
 0.4776968154779486;
 0.0006174969242414622]
TRANSLATION: [-0.8762639669385905;
 -0.4808546299239073;
 0.03066406896983919]
TRANSLATION: [0.8820850695684039;
 0.4710895097519138;
 0.000777075418202299]
TRANSLATION: [-0.838846170104902;
 -0.5443683104889697;
 -0.000495414697272841]
```

```
#include "readProcess.h"

int readProcess(char *videoPath) {

    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(videoPath); 

    render(); 

    Ptr<ORB> orb = ORB::create();
    BFMatcher matcher(NORM_HAMMING);

    Mat descriptors, prevDescriptors;
    bool descriptorInit = false;

    Mat prevFrame;
    std::vector<KeyPoint> prevKeypoints;

    int totalPositive = 0, maxPositive = 0;
    int index = 0;

    Mat essentialMatrix;
    Mat rotation, translation;

    while(true) {

        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame;

        if (frame.empty()) {
            break;
        }

        Mat grey;
        cvtColor(frame, grey, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        std::vector<Point2f> corners;
        goodFeaturesToTrack(grey, corners, 3000, 0.01, 3);

        std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
        for(const Point2f& corner : corners) {
            keypoints.emplace_back(corner, 1.0f);
        }
        
        orb->compute(grey, keypoints, descriptors);

        if(descriptorInit) {
            std::vector<std::vector<DMatch>> matches;
            matcher.knnMatch(prevDescriptors, descriptors, matches, 2);

            std::vector<DMatch> threshMatches;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < matches.size(); ++i) {
                if (matches[i][0].distance < 0.7 * matches[i][1].distance) {
                    threshMatches.push_back(matches[i][0]);
                }
            }

            std::vector<Point2f> prevMatches, currMatches;
            for(const DMatch& match : threshMatches) {
                prevMatches.push_back(prevKeypoints[match.queryIdx].pt);
                currMatches.push_back(keypoints[match.trainIdx].pt);

                //std::cout << "PREV: " << prevKeypoints[match.queryIdx].pt << std::endl;
                //std::cout << "CURR: " << keypoints[match.trainIdx].pt << std::endl;
            }

            //Fix coefficients somehow after
            essentialMatrix = findEssentialMat(prevMatches, currMatches, 1.0, Point2d(0,0), RANSAC);

            Mat R1, R2, t;
            decomposeEssentialMat(essentialMatrix, R1, R2, t);

            std::cout << "TRANSLATION: " << t << std::endl;

            Mat imgMatches;
            drawMatches(prevFrame, prevKeypoints, frame, keypoints, threshMatches, imgMatches);
            imshow("ORB Matches", imgMatches);
        }
        
        /*for (const Point2f& corner : corners) {
            circle(frame, corner, 5, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
        }*/

        prevDescriptors = descriptors;
        prevFrame = frame;
        prevKeypoints = keypoints;
        descriptorInit = true;

        //imshow("ORB", frame);

        for(MatchCoord x : matchCoordVec) {
            //std::cout << x.x << " " << x.y << " " << x.z << std::endl;
        }

        if(waitKey(1) == 'q') {
            break;
        }
    }

    cap.release();
    destroyAllWindows();

    return 0;


}
```

I have tried looking through all the code and can't seem to really find anything that could cause this

Answer (score 0):

The pose returned by `decomposeEssentialMat` is only up to scale, meaning the translation part only encodes the direction information, even though it is a 3D vector.

To recover scale, you will need additional sensor(s), either a stereo pair or an IMU would help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :). I think the main issue I have right now is that the direction is totally wrong (x and y are near max for the unit vector when they should be 0 and z should be near 1 while it is 0). Any clue why I'm seeing this? Thanks!